# static final variable's value

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm analysing source codes with Sonar API and one of my rules is visiting annotations.

Some annotations may have a Kind.MEMBER_SELECT in it, like when the argument references to a static final variable. I would like to know if there is a way to get this variable's value, knowing it is final.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that with a custom rule as for now would be to navigate to the declaration of the referenced value and that would be possible only if this declaration is within the same compilation unit as your annotation (so not the most common case).

In short : not easily and not for the general case.

We have no real plan to support this in SonarJava in the upcoming future.

Comment: Thanks! So I can only get the variable's value if It's in the same file. Even if it's in the same package but in other file I won't be able to get the value. Did i understand well? I don't know much about the compilation unit possibilities in Sonar.

Comment: Yes, that's right : if it is in the same file you will have a way to access the declaration and thus the value but it is not possible if the constant is defined in another file.